# How can I call an external service from Sitecore and include its response into the layout service using JSS

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9, sitecore-jss

I want to know how we can call an external service from Sitecore and include the retrieved data from its response into the layout service using JSS.

We manage the core Product data in Sitecore and also build a micro service to serve the frequently updated data such as Price. So, we would like Sitecore to call our micro service to retrieve the product price data and then show it in front-end along with other product data stored in Sitecore.

Could you please advise me on the right approach using Sitecore JSS?

Comment: Can you be more specific which service you want to include.And explain your requirement.

Comment: Its a microservice we built. Data is partially from micoservice, like price of product. Other product details are in site core